# 1-serializability theorem in database theory

Tags: concurrency, database-theory, databases

In the paper "[MVCC@TODS'1983 by Bernstein et al.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=319998)", 1-serializability ($1$-$\text{SR}$) problem is defined as a decision problem:

> To decide whether an MV (multi-version) log $L$ is $1$-$\text{SR}$.

where,

> An MV (multi-version) log $L$ is $1$-$\text{SR}$ iff there exists a version order $\ll$ such that MVSG($L,\ll$) is acyclic.

I did not get the points of the following comment in page 475:

> Our problem corresponds to choosing versions at the same time as scheduling the operations.

How to understand this comment? Has not the schedule been fixed once an MV log $L$ is given? Are the terms "choosing" and "scheduling" related to implementations?